# Automation: trigger a set of tickets

Tags: jira

Is it possible to automate the generation of the same tickets (stories) with 'parameters' (i.e. minimal changes in e.g. Title, Epic)? We are working on a digital transformation project with 10 products for 20 markets in 4 brands (i.e. 800 projects). We would like to automatically create a set of Jira tickets for each of them. Is that possible? Is there a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you can do a csv import. You first need to create a .csv, of course, following typical Excel csv format.

No plugin is needed.

More details available in the Atlassian documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/importing-data-from-csv-802592885.html

WBM link in case of future link rot: https://web.archive.org/web/20210428151403/https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/importing-data-from-csv-802592885.html